# ¿Cómo detectar que un JPanel es visible para el usuario?

Tags: java, java-swing

Quiero crear un listener que me permita ejecutar código en un `JPanel` en el momento que este se haga visible al usuario o se oculte. En ocasiones llamó el panel dentro de un `JDialog` o directamente el `JFrame` principal. Estoy intentando con esto:

```
ComponentListener c = new ComponentAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "revisar si se actualizan comoponente. ");
            }

            };


        this.addComponentListener(c);
```

Pero no obtengo el resultado deseado.

---

**Actualización**

Estoy usando esta clase para mis paneles:

```
public abstract class JPanelBase extends JPanel{
        JPanelBase(){
             //AQUÍ DEFINO MI EVENTO...
        }

        //AQUI MIS OPERACIONES....
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno, encontre la respuesta en el foro en ingles [aqui.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2728764/4326551)

Y esta fue mi implementación:

```
public abstract class JPanelBase extends JPanel implements HierarchyListener{

private boolean amIVisbile(){
        Container c = getParent();
        while(c != null){
            if (!c.isVisible()) {
                return false;
            } else {
                c = c.getParent();
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void addNotify(){
        super.addNotify();
        addHierarchyListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void removeNotify(){
        removeHierarchyListener(this);
        super.removeNotify();
    }

    @Override
    public void hierarchyChanged(HierarchyEvent e){
        System.out.println("Cambio en la jeraquia.");
        if(amIVisible()){
          //EJECUTO MI CODIGO. 
          }
    } 
}
```